# Difference between static private, private, static public, public

Tags: haxe

Could someone please explain what is the difference in Haxe syntax when it comes to functions and variables.

```
public var theName;
```

vs

```
static public var theName;
```

or

```
static private var theName;
```

vs

```
private var theName;
```

and same for function for ex.

`static private function(){}` vs `private function(){}`

Answer (score 6):

There are two scopes

```
static
```

which refers to the class. That is that it can be referenced by the class reference and the name.

```
ClassName.reference();
```

would be:

```
class ClassName{
    static public function reference(){
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

And the other, which refers to a class instance constructed using the new operator.

```
new ClassName().reference();
```

Which would be:

```
class ClassName{
    public function new(){
       //We need a constructor.
    }
    public function reference(){
        return "hello world"
    }
```

The other is a choice:

```
public / private
```

refers to the availability of the reference outside of the type scope.

```
private function reference(){
   return "hello world";
}
```

Would only be available when called where the `this` variable refers to the class instance in question. so: `this.reference()` compiles but `new ClassName().reference()` will not.

```
static private function ....
```

has a similar effect, in that it is only available where the class is local

```
class MyClass{
   private static function unavailable(){
       return "available";
   }
   public static function available(){
       return something();
   }
}
class Main(){
   static public function main(){
       MyClass.unavaliable()//will not compile
       MyClass.available()//good to go.
   }
}
```

Comment: A minor detail: `public`/`private` refers to the availability of the reference outside of the _type_ where it is defined.  Given `private function reference() {...}`, `new ClassName().reference()` compiles fine if inside another method of the same `ClassName` class (or some subclass of it), even a static one where there is no local `this`, and fails if placed elsewhere.  Related: [visibility on the Haxe Manual](http://haxe.org/manual/class-field-visibility.html) and a [Try Haxe example](http://try.haxe.org/#c21a4).

Answer (score 2):

> static : the field belongs to the Class itself and not to instances of this class. Static identifiers can be used directly in the class itself. Outside of the class, it must be used with the class name (for example : my.pack.MyClass.name).

http://old.haxe.org/ref/oop

Comment: Haxe [access modifier visibility](http://haxe.org/manual/class-field-visibility.html) would be a good page to reference.  Are you https://github.com/andrew-git?

Comment: Good notice, forgot to mention difference between visibility modifiers. Yes, it's my account on git